# To find the volume of the solid under the paraboloid

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the volume of the solid under the paraboloid $z=x^2+ y^2$ and above the region bounded by $y=x^2$ and $x=y^2$.

Comment: Hi David, welcome to MSE! What have you tried? Add your solution or pieces of solution to the question, and it will receive much better answers!

Answer (score 1):

We can define the desired area on the xy plane as follows:
$$A\ \colon\ 0\leq x\leq 1\ ,\ x^{2}\leq y\leq\sqrt{x}$$
We calculate the volume of the area using this double integral:
$$V=\int\limits_{A}{(x^{2}+y^{2})dxdy}=\int\limits_{x=0}^{x=1}{\int\limits_{y=x^{2}}^{y=\sqrt{x}}{(x^{2}+y^{2})dydx}}$$
$$={\int\limits_{x=0}^{x=1}{\left[{{{y^{3}}\over{3}}+x^{2}y}\right]}}_{y=x^{2}}^{y=\sqrt{x}}dx=\int\limits_{x=0}^{x=1}{(}{{x^{{{3}\over{2}}}}\over{3}}+x^{{{5}\over{2}}}-{{x^{6}}\over{3}}-x^{4})dx$$
$$={\left[{{{2}\over{15}}x^{{{5}\over{2}}}+{{2}\over{7}}x^{{{7}\over{2}}}-{{x^{7}}\over{21}}-{{x^{5}}\over{5}}}\right]}_{0}^{1}={{2}\over{15}}+{{2}\over{7}}-{{1}\over{21}}-{{1}\over{5}}={{14+30-5-21}\over{105}}={{18}\over{105}}={{6}\over{35}}\simeq .171$$

Comment: Hi Arashostami, I see this is your first answer to a question on this site. By the guidelines, we do not want to answer questions that do not have sufficient effort shown by the OP. This site is not intended for students (or sometimes bots) to post problem statements and receive solutions. Instead, it's to clarify or help people get past a sticking point in a solution.